# CNAME vs A Record for WWW - with 301 Redirects

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I am using a 301 redirect plugin: [Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/) and my site's URL is `http://example.com` <-- notice no `www`. This works great for the following scenario:

#### User types: *example.com/campaign*

My redirect of `/campaign/ => http://example.com/longer-campaign-page-slug` works. Awesome. However, this next scenario does not work:

#### User types: *www.example.com/campaign*

WordPress either 404s or tries to redirect to the most closely-named post (this is default behavior of WordPress as far as I can tell). Example, user lands at `http://example.com/campaign-from-last-month` because it is similarly named.

I tried adding this to `.htaccess` but it did nothing:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Keep in mind, regular requests to actual pages work. For example: `http://www.example.com/super/awesome/slug/path` will successfully land to `http://example.com/super/awesome/slug/path`.

The **www** record is a CNAME to the **A** record. Would having both of these be their own **A** record (to same IP) improve the situation? Or is there another solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Put that *before* WordPress rewrite.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```